# How to draw an image based on polygon coordinates Java

Tags: java, coordinates, draw, polygons

I'm making my first game(asteroids) and until now I have been using a polygon as the space ship however I'd like to use an image I drew instead. How do I take what I have and draw the image so it behaves like the polygon did?

My draw method:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    AffineTransform at = g.getTransform();
    g.translate(position.x, position.y);
    double rot = direction.angle() + Math.PI / 2;
    g.rotate(rot);
    g.scale(DRAWING_SCALE, DRAWING_SCALE);
    g.setColor(COLOR);
    g.fillPolygon(XP, YP, XP.length);
    if (thrusting) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillPolygon(XPTHRUST, YPTHRUST, XPTHRUST.length);
    }
    g.setTransform(at);
}
```

My coordinate arrays:

```
public int[] XP = {0,1,0,-1}; //sets the position of the ship
public int[] YP = {1,-1,0,-1};
public int[] XPTHRUST = {0,1,0,-1}; //sets position of thrust
public int[] YPTHRUST = {-3,-1,0,-1};
```